# HttpWebRequest - adding data

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, saml

I am building `HttpWebRequest` to request a response containing a `SAMLResponse` to obtain a users name.
The response will be picked up by a `Httpmodule`.
After building my `AuthRequest` (as follows) the xml is defalted, base64 encoded then url encoded.

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol xmlns:saml=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion ProtocolBinding=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST  Version= version ID= iD 
IssueInstant=DateTime.Now.ToString() Destination= destination />

<saml:Issuer> issuer /saml:Issuer>

<samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate=true Format=urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient/>    
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

My postBytes for `requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length)` consists of a `byte[]` from a string created from `"SAMLRequest=" + SAMLRequest`

Hopefully I havent lost you yet.
My question is: does the value of SAMLRequest need to be placed in a form or can it be the encoded xml? What determines this decision?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did I understand this correctly: Are you writing an authentication httpmodule in which you are planning to add your SAML xml to the httprequest? What is happening in which step of the http pipeline?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to add the SAML xml to the request and send it to the IdP. There the user will authenticate and a new request will be sent and caught in on PreRequestHandlerExecute event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [saml.xml.org](http://saml.xml.org/wiki/sp-initiated-single-sign-on-postartifact-bindings): The post request issued to the IdP has the following content:

```
POST /SAML2/SSO/POST HTTP/1.1
Host: idp.example.org
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: nnn
SAMLRequest=request&RelayState=token
```

You can of course [assemble a HttpWebRequest in C# code](http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx) with this form content in order to avoid issues related to nested forms.

The saml.xml.org link specifies that "*The value of the SAMLRequest parameter is the base64 encoding of the* `<samlp:AuthnRequest>` *element*"

If you have an IdP (like [OpenSSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSO)) available you should be able to test and see what works.

I am assuming that you are trying to implement Step 3 in the diagram below.

DISCLAIMER: I Haven't tried this out myself, so please provide some feedback on whether this answer was helpful or not.
[image]

Comment: In the event a user fails authentication or their request does not contain a SAMLResponse, they are presented with a option to try again. clicking this button will generate a HttpWebRequest with the SAML AuthnRequest.(my original Q was how to attach this) The diagram isnt a perfect representation but it would be a combination of steps 3 and 5.

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. My question is: the value of request from SAMLRequest=request; should it be the encoded xml authRequest or a form containing the encoded authRequest as a hidden field? [btw thanks for your help]

Comment: AHH thanks you! i cant believe i missed that line! The value of the SAMLRequest parameter is the base64 encoding of the <samlp:AuthnRequest> element"

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks yourself: I learned some stuff researching this as well.